# your php installation be missing the MySQL extension Wordpress CPANEL

Tags: php

I download the last wordpress and try install, but wp show this

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which
> is required by WordPress

This happend wen i change to PHP 7.x

When i change to 5.6 work fine but i need use PHP 7.x

[image: error]

CPANEL

[image: phpv]

PHP INFO Show me thist but i select and saved PHP 7
[image: phopinfi]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the hosting not wordpress

EDIT:
Just send the capture and link of your website to the hosting company and tell them to correctly update the PHP version and install the necessary libraries on the server to run wordpress

Comment: @Rup Done......